# creating shortcut key to all forms

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I am planning to create a shortcut key to all my forms, I put this code to all my forms

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyDown +=new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        }

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                Button1.PerformClick();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                button2.PerformClick();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }
```

is there any way, so that I will not repeat this codes in all my forms,
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Form Base Class ... there you can write the code and inherit all the forms from that Base Form.

**[Raise Base Class Events in Derived Classes (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**